# How to find number of distinct Class labels in a Dataset?

Tags: dataset, weka, data-mining

I am trying to figure out   how to determine the number of class labels in a dataset used in Data Mining. Can anyone please help me?

For example in the weather.nomimal dataset that is provided by weka

Comment: You can count them? Also, if you need specific help then you need to ask a specific question (i.e. with some code examples, something you have tried, or at least a language specification so users can better help you).

Comment: So if your dataset has A, B, C classes then you want 3 as your answer?

Comment: Are you looking for unique class labels or total?

Answer (score 1):

in Weka Explorer you open the dataset and the number of instances, the number of distinct instances etc,  is shown in the top right of the panel.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Class label is weka datasets is usually the last attribute. In case of weather.nominal dataset, the class label is "play" that is binary.